# how to set custom Horizantal divider line to menu android?

Tags: android, menu

I want to set customised horizantal bar to my options menu.how to do that?Is there any method or attribut available?

Please dont give link of setMenuBackgound() method already available in stack overflow.

Regards,
Android Developer